# cant send message with facebook graph api

Tags: json, django, facebook-graph-api

in my django project
i have this function:

```
def mesaj_yolla():
    fbid="my_facebook_id"
    post_message_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<my_access_token>'
    response_msg = json.dumps({"recipient":{"id":fbid}, "message":{"text":"hello"}})
    status = requests.post(post_message_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},data=response_msg)
    print(status)
```

it returns: `<Response [400]>`

what is wrong with these codes? i just want to send a message to user.

Comment: you cannot send messages from user to user. there is no api for that. there is not even a /user/messages endpoint, not sure where you got this idea from?

Comment: i tried section 4 in https://abhaykashyap.com/blog/post/tutorial-how-build-facebook-messenger-bot-using-django-ngrok
i have an app on facebook developer.

Comment: messenger bots are for communication between pages and users, there is no api for user to user communication.

Comment: yes, i have a page already

Comment: are you using a page token? is the fbid a user id of a user who actually started using the bot already?

Comment: yes, i uses. fbid is my id which is admin of app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147532/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-luschn).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference), you should use `recipients.id` instead of `recipients.user_id`:

```
def mesaj_yolla():
    fbid="my_facebook_id"
    post_message_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<my_access_token>'
    response_msg = json.dumps({"recipient":{"id":fbid}, "message":{"text":"hello"}})
    status = requests.post(post_message_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},data=response_msg)
    print(status)
```

That explains the HTTP 400 code (Bad request).

Comment: sorry, i wrote mistakely, i forgot to change this. However it doesnt still works